# Issue in Custom Navigation tab in angular2?

Tags: angular

I want to create a navigation tab which when clicked leads to corresponding tab (id='tab-1', id='tab-2', id='tab-3').

But, getting no idea here how to implement the logic here. Please help me solve the issue.

Any other similar approach is also welcomed.

### app.component.ts

```
tabName = ['tab1','tab2','tab3']

tabsUL(){

}
```

### app.component.html

```
    <div class="pull-left  text-center" style="position:relative;cursor:pointer;width:100%;">
    <ul class=" nav nav-tabs " role="tablist">
    <li class="tab-link" *ngFor="let tab of tabName; let i = index;" [ngStyle]="{'width': 'calc(100% /' + tabName.length + ')'}">
    <a  (click)="tabsUL($event)" href="#tab-{{i+1}}" role="tab">{{tab}}</a>
    </li>
    </ul> 
    </div>
<div id="tab-1" class="tab-content rmpm" role="tabpanel">
            tab1 content
</div>
<div id="tab-2" class="tab-content rmpm" role="tabpanel">
            tab2 content
</div>
<div id="tab-3" class="tab-content rmpm" role="tabpanel">
            tab3 content
</div>
```

Comment: There's also [angular material tabs exist](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview)

Comment: The issue is I am not using angular material in my project and need above approach for creating custom component. But, stucked here. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Several ways to do this, but this should get you going. You don't need routes.

In your html, you can be more efficient with *ngFor, then use *ngIf to control what to hide and what to show

in your **app.component.html**

```
<div class="tab">
  <button (click)="selectTab = tab" class="tab-link" *ngFor="let tab of tabName; let i = index;" [ngStyle]="{'width': 'calc(100% /' + tabName.length + ')'}"> {{tab}}
    </button>
</div>

<div *ngFor="let tab of tabName;let i = index">
  <div *ngIf="selectTab === tab"  [attr.id]="'tab-' + (i+1)" class="tab-content rmpm" role="tabpanel">
    {{tabContent[i]}}
  </div>
</div>
```

then in your component you can have a select variable
an array of tabs, and array of content (or even combine them)

in your **app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent { 
   tabName = ['tab1','tab2','tab3'];
  tabContent = ['tab1 content', 'tab2 content', 'tab3 content'];
  selectTab = this.tabName[0];

}
```

Added stackblitz example of code demonstrated here
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sv8mtt

Comment: <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content rmpm" role="tabpanel">
            tab1 content that should contain several divs
</div>.   How to put contents here. You have used *ngFor loop. tabContent should not be in the array because that will contain several divs contents . Here, (id='tab-1', id='tab-2', id='tab-3')  is a div that contains tab contents for each tab respectively.

Comment: Can we switch to each tab content(id='tab-1', id='tab-2', id='tab-3') on the click of (click)="selectTab = tab" (each tab)?

Comment: You can assign whatever id you want by property binding, see in answer where we set [attr.id], we increment here by 1 because index starts at 0

Comment: I want to do something like this https://embed.plnkr.co/IvymLd5kIp9JY4AitfrH/. Can u do on plunker so that I understand your code clearly.

Comment: @Ahmadmnzr, What are you confused by? and did you try what have you tried but didn't work?

Comment: How can I show my each tab content on the click of each tab like in this example. embed.plnkr.co/IvymLd5kIp9JY4AitfrH. ? Sorry, I have tried and my tab contents are not displaying on the click..

Comment: @Ahmadmnzr, added live example of code demonstrated here